# Need clarification of Hatcher's definition of $\Delta$-complex

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, simplex

I have a question about Hatcher's definition of $\Delta$-complex.

The standard n-simplex is defined as

$\Delta^n = \{(t_0, ..., t_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} | \sum_{i} t_i = 1, t_i \geq 0\}$

Let $\mathring{\Delta}^n$ denote the interior of a $\Delta$ n-simplex.

From p. 103 of Hatcher:

> A $\Delta$-complex structure on a space X is defined as a collection of maps $\sigma_{\alpha} : \Delta^n \rightarrow X$, with n depending on the index $\alpha$, such that:
>
> (i) The restriction $\sigma_{\alpha} | \mathring{\Delta}^n$ is injective, and each point of X is in the image of exactly one such restriction.
>
> (ii) Each restriction of $\sigma_{\alpha}$ to a face of $\Delta^n$ is one of the maps $\sigma_{\beta} : \Delta^{n-1} \rightarrow X$.
>
> (iii) A set $A \subset X$ is open iff $\sigma_{\alpha}^{-1}(A)$ is open in $\Delta^n$ for each $\sigma_{\alpha}$.

*Question:*  Take the 1-dimensional simplex corresponding to the interval [0,1], with three maps (the 1-dimensional simplex map plus two 0-simplex maps as required by condition ii).  Then this space fails to be a $\Delta$-simplex because the end points of the interval are not in the image of any interior point of either $\Delta^1$ (since they are endpoints) or $\Delta^0$ (since the interior of a point set is empty).  Is this correct?  It seems strange that a 1-simplex does not count itself as a $\Delta-$simplex under this definition.

Comment: By convention, the interior of a $0$-simplex is itself.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown if that is true, then what prevents me from defining a $\Delta$-complex structure on a space by making every point the image of a 0-complex?  Hatcher says this is prevented by his definition, but since every single point 0-complex is open in itself, then condition iii (and i and ii) are satisfied.

Comment: @user334137: Can you explain exactly what definition you have in mind, and why you think conditions (i) and (iii) will be satisfied?  Note that condition (iii) says "iff", so you need the implication to go both ways.

Comment: The topology on the space $X$ is already given. So, for example, perhaps it is given that the topology on $X$ is not the discrete topology. In that case you cannot give $X$ a $\Delta$-complex structure that makes every single point open, for that would imply that $X$ *does* have the discrete topology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hatcher defines the interior of $\Delta^n$ as $\Delta^n\setminus\partial\Delta^n$.  Here $\partial\Delta^n$ is defined as the union of the faces of $\Delta^n$, where a face can be obtained by removing one vertex and taking the convex hull of the remaining vertices.  In the case $n=0$, there is only one vertex, so upon removing it the complex hull is empty and so $\partial\Delta^0$ is empty (actually, it is conventional to say that $\Delta^0$ has no faces rather than saying it has one face which is the empty set, but in any case $\partial\Delta^0$ is definitely the empty set).  So the interior of $\Delta^0$ is not empty, but is instead $\Delta^0$ itself.

Comment: I have a similar question as the OP, and you've addressed almost all of it. However, Since $\overset{\circ}{\Delta^0}=\Delta^0,$ then using criteria(iii), we then would force every vertex to constitute an open set, since $\sigma_\alpha\mid \overset{\circ}{\Delta^0}$ is homeomorphic onto its image. My problem is that (i) together with (iii) and the convention that the interior of a $0-$complex is itself leads me to see that *some points must be open.* How is it that we can have this convention, but not open points by the definition of a  $\Delta-$complex?

Comment: I'm not sure how you are concluding that a vertex must be open.  Keep in mind that to apply criterion (iii) you need $\sigma_{\alpha}^{-1}(A)$ to be open simultaneously for *all* $\alpha$.

Comment: Take $\Delta^0=\{1\},$ obviously with the indiscrete topology. The preimage is open trivially, and the image $\{\sigma_\alpha(1)\}$ is only open in the subspace topology inherited from $X.$ I was over thinking the homeomorphic part of the statement "homeomorphic onto its image" and under thinking the *onto its image* part of the statement. I appreciate prompt reply. Thank you.